# Lat/Long WFS GetFeature query - ArcGIS verses GeoServer geospatial data servers

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-server, latitude-longitude, getfeature

We could be querying a GeoServer or ArcGIS server for WFS features (v1.1.0).  However I'm finding that GeoServer takes the envelope bounds in LONG/LAT and ArcGIS takes them in LAT/LONG.  The use of `srsName="EPSG:..."` doesn't seem to have any affect on the input coordinates.

Is this a known situation and is there any reliable solution to cater for this? I see a GeoServer `ows:keyword` for GeoServer but ArcGIS doesn't have anything like this.  I think this would be unreliable.  They each have different endpoints (`wfs` verses `WFSServer`) though this too is unreliable.

This is a significant issue though I can't see anyone else has had this problem so I feel I must be missing something obvious. Or no one else is trying to hit more than one type of geospatial data servers.

Is this a known problem?

For example.

GeoServer server - http://geossdi.dmp.wa.gov.au:80/services/wfs

POST -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.1.0"
                xmlns:gsml="urn:cgi:xmlns:CGI:GeoSciML:2.0"
                xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
                xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
                xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows"
                xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
                xmlns:er="urn:cgi:xmlns:GGIC:EarthResource:1.1"
                maxFeatures="200"                resultType="results">
<wfs:Query typeName="gsml:Borehole">
    <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:BBOX>
            <ogc:PropertyName>gsml:collarLocation/gsml:BoreholeCollar/gsml:location</ogc:PropertyName>
            <gml:Envelope srsName="EPSG:4326"><gml:lowerCorner>37.0 -55.0 </gml:lowerCorner><gml:upperCorner>229.0 12.0 </gml:upperCorner></gml:Envelope>
        </ogc:BBOX>
    </ogc:Filter>
</wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

ArcGIS server - http://www.ga.gov.au/gis/services/topography/National_Onshore_Gas_Pipelines/MapServer/WFSServer?

Post -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.1.0"
                xmlns:gsml="urn:cgi:xmlns:CGI:GeoSciML:2.0"
                xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
                xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
                xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows"
                xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
                xmlns:er="urn:cgi:xmlns:GGIC:EarthResource:1.1"
                maxFeatures="200"                resultType="results">
    <wfs:Query typeName="topography_National_Onshore_Gas_Pipelines:Gas_Pipelines">
        <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:BBOX>
                <ogc:PropertyName>SHAPE</ogc:PropertyName>
                <gml:Envelope><gml:lowerCorner>-55.0 37.0</gml:lowerCorner><gml:upperCorner>12.0 229.0</gml:upperCorner></gml:Envelope>
            </ogc:BBOX>
        </ogc:Filter>
    </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

Comment: In WFS 1.1.0 srsName should be given as `"urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326"`. GeoServer is using the same axis order as in WFS 1.0.0 if srsName is given with just `EPSG:4326` http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/basics.html. However, without srsName in the filter GeoServer should also use the lat-lon order so you may have found a bug or wrong configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-6216, older versions of GeoServer had a bug where with an app-schema complex feature the axis ordering is always long/lat, even with WFS 2.0.0 requests or specifying the srs as urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326.

We unfortunately utilise older versions :-(.